# Android custom camera cannot follow phone default camera view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, phonegap-plugins

I read that you need to get the  parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() and parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes() so I did this

```
Camera.Parameters pic = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Size> pic2 = pic.getSupportedPictureSizes();

Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Size> previews = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
Size preview = getOptimalPreviewSize(previews, pic2.get(0).width,pic2.get(0).height);
```

with this to get optimal preview

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

then

```
mFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = preview.height; 
mFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().width = preview.width; 

mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

mFrameLayout.addView(mPreview);
```

I was hoping to get similar preview to as the Camera Intent with custom view similar to instagram, but this shows a rectangle that is flattened as a preview. Is there a way to get the preview and picture size of the default camera and set it to the custom camera?

For some reason when i take a picture there is more content in the saved pic on the left and right than what you see in the preview Layout it looked like it was zoomed but checked zoom and it is at 0. Any tips on how to fix this?

Just another question, can you use the Camera intent on a Layout instead of it opening the default camera?